# Java Servlet always returns HTML code of calling page, upon AJAX GET Request to Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am using Tomcat 7 Java Servlets in the backend of my web app.
The issue that I am facing is that when I perform an HTTP GET Request using jQuery Ajax,the HttpServletResponse always returns the HTML body of the calling page, instead of returning the required data.

jQuery code:

```
            function perform_ajax(view_name) {
                $(function() {
                    var url = 'get-view-data-by-view-name';
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: {view_name: JSON.stringify(view_name)},
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            alert(view_name);
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                            //console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            alert("Error: asdasd");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Servlet code:

```
public void doGet (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String x = req.getParameter("view_name");
    resp.setContentType("application/json");
    resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resp.getWriter().write(x);
}
```

Even if I replace the lastt line of my Servlet code with:

`resp.getWriter().write("aaaa");`

commenting out everything else in the doGet function, the Servlet still returns the Html body of the calling page.

I have been stuck on this for several hours now. Went through scores of SO questions, tried various things like using a different MIME type such as plain, but all I get in response is the Html code of the caller page. Please help me find where I am going wrong and resolve this issue.

Comment: can you also paste in the question what you get on the console  `success: function(data) {
                            
                            console.log(data);
                        },`

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to pass the url in the ajax function call; dont know how I could miss that out!

```
            function perform_ajax(view_name) {
                $(function() {
                    var url = 'get-view-data-by-view-name';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url, // + Added URL to ajax call
                        method: 'GET',
                        data: {view_name: JSON.stringify(view_name)},
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            alert(view_name);
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                            //console.log(data);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr) {
                            alert("Error: asdasd");
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check header, that return get request.
It must have application/json.
But browser may be interpreted text as html.

Use curl for checking work.

And returns JSON object instead of a string, for example:

```
    ...
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String x = req.getParameter("view_name");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("view_name", x);
    out.print(obj);
    ...
```